# Animate function jquery running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Guys I've been wracking my brain for entirely too long on this code.  For the life of me, I cannot figure out why it runs twice every time I click on the link.  Could anyone please take a look at my code and tell me why it's doing this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(function(){

function scrollToAnchor(aid){
var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
$('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: aTag.offset().left}, "slow", function() { console.log("test"); } );
};

$(".forward").click(function() {
    var div_name = $(this).attr("href");
    scrollToAnchor(div_name);
});

});//]]>
```

HTML

```
<div class="next">
    <span style="font-size:48px;"><a class="forward" href="#id2">&nbsp;></a></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.next{
    position:fixed;
    padding:10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    top:48%;
    right:0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    z-index:201;
}
.next a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
.next a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: red;
}
```

Each time you click on "forward" it should only log "test" to the console once but it is logging it twice.

Comment: maybe because you are animating html and body tag?

Comment: *sigh*  I've seriously been staring at this code for hours.  I removed the html tag and left the body and it stopped running it twice.  Fender, you are awesome.  Thank you so much!  Now I can sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just adding my comment as answer for other having the same problem:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: aTag.offset().left}, "slow", function() { console.log("test"); } );
};
```

`$('html,body')` cause the html tag AND the body tag to be animated, so the animation seems to run twice.
Just change it to `$('body')` to fix this.

Comment: Thanks again Fender!  I honestly don't know how I missed that.  I guess I thought it was a "both" rather than an "and".  Obviously, I need to get some sleep.